# C# Speech recognition Won't answer me

Tags: c#, voice, speech

I made this simple code but it doesn't seem to recognise my voice. I tried everything from using another input(microphone) to reading the exceptions. It always goes to 'something is wrong' directly. Can someone check my code for faults? Or if you had the same problem, how can I solve it? I have been searching for a while on the internet also but I can't find a proper answer.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Threading;

namespace voice_bot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        Choices list = new Choices();
        public Form1()
        {
            SpeechRecognitionEngine rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

            list.Add(new String[] { "hello", "how are you" });

            Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(list));
            s.Speak("hello, my name is voice bot. If you would like to talk with me, go ahead");

            try
            {
                rec.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                rec.LoadGrammar(gr);
                rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeachRecognized;
                rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                s.Speak("Something went wrong");    
            }          

        }

        public void say(String h)
        {
            s.Speak(h);
        }





        private void rec_SpeachRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string r = e.Result.Text;


            if (r == "hello")
            {            
                s.Speak("hi");                
            }

            if (r == "how are you")
            {
                s.Speak("good, how are you?");               
            }
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it goes to "Something went wrong", then an exception has been thrown. Look at the exception and see what it is telling you. If you don't understand it, you can add the **text** of the exception to your question.

Comment: Well the issue is in the Try block,  What happens when you step through it?  Where does it error?  Also what are the values for the exception e?  Those things will help you determine the issue.

Comment: Okay so the exception says: "System.PlatformNotSupportedException". I am new with speech recognition so I don't really know how to solve it.

Comment: the exception also say which line went wrong, you can check that!

Comment: That error just means what ever you are using is not supported on the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what platform you're trying this on, but `System.Speech` is very VERY old.

You might try the latest speech platform from Microsoft (note: I worked on both System.Speech and on this latest speech platform). You can checkout the new platform here: https://aka.ms/speech/sdk. There are a bunch of samples that should lead you very quickly to a working solution, and it works on "all" modern platform operating systems (windows, linux, android, ios, mac, etc.) and via "all" modern programming languages (c++, c#, java, javascript, python, objective-c, swift, etc...)

--robch